# How to create a working windows xp usb stick in Ubuntu14.04? & how to dual boot with it

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows, live-usb

Hello,My dear friends.I need your help.
I have windows xp iso file in my pc .I want to create a bootable usb stick for it and install windows xp along with Ubuntu ,but I don't know how.winusb software not working with windows xp.please help meeee.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any USB live creator available for Ubuntu. A simple google search can bring up many such applications.

However the process of installing a new windows partition can be difficult and run into problems with grub or hard disk partitioning . Instead I would recommend you to use a Virtual Machine instead of installing Windows XP on the hard drive.

P.S. -Windows does not support live USB support, according to my knowledge. You could only create a usb installer for windows XP.